# Questions about Metadata

Tags: breeze

Wanted to get some clarity on something in regards to how we are implementing our Metadata.

Our Breeze Api is not directly tied to SQL Server so we have implemented a custom EFContextProvider and the DbSet below....

```
public class MetadataDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MetadataDbContext()
        : base(nameOrConnectionString: "MetadataDb")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MetadataDbContext>(null);
    }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderMeter> OrderMeters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDemand> OrderDemand { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MeterHistory> MeterHistory { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FieldTech> FieldTechs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dispatcher> Dispatchers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderLookupData> LookupData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Alert> Alert { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

As you can see I am pointing that DbSet at a database called "MetadataDb" which is just an sdf file we deploy with our project.  We then override SaveChangesCore in the Context Provider to route our saves to the correct services instead of going direct to Entity Framework.  My question is during some testing we noticed that it seemed Breeze was trying to update the sdf file in some cases.  It did not appear that the size of the file changed, but just wanted to make sure before we go to production that the sdf file we are pointing the Metadata at does not grow on our server.

Thanks really enjoy using Breeze.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that you are using the .sdf file for is to return metadata then Breeze doesn't do anything more than extract the "edmx" from the ObjectContext or DbContext associated with your database.  My guess is that just the act of spinning up the context is causing EF to "modify" the "sdf" file.  Breeze is **not** doing anything to touch the database directly.